# Get generic delegate return type

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I got a c# method which receives a generic `Delegate` as a parameter and after invocation checks the type of the result:

```
public async Task<TResult> InvokeAction<TResult>(Delegate action, object[] actionArgs = null)
{
...
    var result = action.DynamicInvoke(actionArgs);
    if (result is Task<TResult> task) return await task;
}
```

Is there a way I can check in advanced if the return type of the delegate parameter is indeed `TResult` without the need to invoke it first? This without changing the parameter the `Func<TResult>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Delegate.Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.method?view=net-5.0)'s `ReturnType`:

```
  Func<int> action = () => 1;
  Delegate a = action;
  Console.WriteLine(a.Method.ReturnType); // prints System.Int32
```

Comment: And then to check if the type is indeed TResult like my method declares, is the correct comparison code supposed to  be a.Method.ReturnType == typeof(TResult) ?

Comment: @YonatanNir Yes. But more common approach is to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom`.